# 2-dimensional traverse algorithm with constraint

Tags: algorithm, queue

Given a 2-dimensional array of width `m` and height `n`.

I want to put all cells into a queue so that my `k`-thread program can handle them.

However, one important constraint is that there will be conflicts when two 8-direction neighbor cells (e.g. `(2,3),(2,4)`, `(2,3),(3,3)` and `(2,3),(3,4)`) are both being processed.

How can I find an algorithm to generate such a queue, hopefully in `O(m*n)` time?

BTW, I have managed to limit `k < m*n/4` (if that is already safe or tell me how small I have to limit `k` to be safe) to avoid cases like `m=8,n=8,k=64`.

Comment: Does `(2,2)` and `(3,3)` (diagonal) consider as neighbors?

Comment: @DavidWinder Yes, 8 directions will be considered as neighbours.

Comment: It is interesting question. What are the scale of `n`, `m`, `k`? around 0-10? 0-100? 0-1000?

Comment: @DavidWinder `k` is the number of cores, so it is 1-64. `m` and `n` depend on scale, so they can be 1-10000.

Comment: Are conflicts tolerable but to be minimized, or purely disallowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust disallowed please :)

Comment: @MoYummy: then it is impossible to implement that without inter-thread synchronization means.

Answer (score 1):

To start:

Divide array into k rectangular regions.

Scan all regions by diagonals in zigzag order from the left top corner like this:

```
  (0,0)-(1,0)-(0,1)-(2,0)-(1,1)-(0,2)-(3,0)-(2,1)-(1,2)-(0,3)...
```

Seems that with this scheme treatment of neigbors is separated "by time", so probability of conflicts  - *they might occur when speeds of different threads execution differ* -  is rather low.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, an effective strategy is to split the array in k rectangles along the long side and to fill them row by row along the short side. Fill every other rectangle in one direction and conversely. There will be a long delay between two threads working along a common edge, and if they ever do, they will do it very briefly in neighboring cells (if I am right, they can conflict at most on three cells).

---

If conflicts are forbidden, split in k rectangles and let every thread fill the bottom half (any order). Then let them wait at a barrier. Then let them fill the second half.

You can also implement k-1 mutexes to forbid the pairs of neighboring threads to act on neighboring halves.